# How do I get so called title and part of the body of a certain output

Tags: linux, text-processing

```
Ltm::xxx

not
the
line

Cache
first
second

Ltm::

not
the
line

Cache
first
second
```

I have an output as above. How do I get the 'Ltm::' followed by the two lines after 'Cache' inclusive. Sample output would be:

```
Ltm::xxx

Cache
first
second
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify your requirements in more detail. What is the exact condition to find the lines to be printed. lines 6, 7 and 8 after `Ltm::xxx`? Text following the second empty line after `Ltm::xxx` up to the third empty line or EOF? Everything starting with the first occurrence of `Cache` after `Ltm::xxx` up to the next empty line or EOF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *`Ltm::` followed by the two lines after `Cache` inclusive*, using `sed`, including blank line after `Ltm`:

```
sed -n -e '/^Ltm::/,+1p' -e '/Cache/,+2p' < file.txt
```

Tested with GNU and BusyBox.

Comment: How do I insert a blank line after each string 'second'. I am thinking of sed -n -e '/^Ltm::/,+1p' -e '/Cache/,+2p' -e '/second/a how_to_add_blank_line' < file.txt.

Comment: use the `a` command. for example `sed -e '/second/a\' -e ''` appends an empty line after each line matching `second`

Comment: Tqvm, it works!

Comment: Please [edit] and add the additional info from the comment to the answer... comments can (and tend to) be cleaned up and deleted.